# Copying one feature attribute to other feature using FME

Tags: shapefile, fme-form

I have two features road and bridges. Road feature had an attribute `UniqueID` as string. I have a attribute field in bridge `UponID`. I want to copy road unique id to bridge Upon Id field. How to do it using FME?

Comment: How do you know which feature to copy the attribute to?  Is there another field that you can use to link the features together?

Comment: What types of geometry? Guess roads are lines and bridges are points? Very much different ways to do this but NeighborFinder might be the correct Transformer.

Comment: As others have suggested, what are you trying to accomplish by doing this? How are you tying the data together to make sure that you are copying the correct attribute from one feature into the attribute table of the other feature?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you would want the PointOnLineOverlayer transformer. That will transfer the road UniqueID from the road (line feature) to the bridge (point feature).

Then use an AttributeManager transformer on the point output to rename the attribute (or copy its value) from UniqueID to UponID